# How to pull data from one table based on a temp table SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

The query I have currently:

```
SELECT   
    E.FILEKEY,
    (SELECT MAX(EFFDATE) 
     FROM
         (SELECT B.FILEKEY, B.STATUS AS STATUS, B.EFFDATE 
          FROM TABLEB B
          UNION
          SELECT A.FILEKEY, A.STATUS2 AS STATUS, A.EFFDATE2 AS EFFDATE 
          FROM TABLEA A) C
     WHERE C.EFFDATE <= '5/1/2011'),   
    A.STATUS
FROM 
    TABLE1 A 
INNER JOIN 
    TABLE2 B ON A.FILEKEY = B.FILEKEY
GROUP BY 
    A.FILEKEY, A.STATUS
```

The union of `tableA` and `tableB` (table C) produces these results:

```
FILEKEY STATUS  EFFDATE
----------------------------------------
1          0    2009-01-01 00:00:00.000
1          1    2010-01-01 00:00:00.000
1          0    2011-01-01 00:00:00.000
1          1    2012-01-01 00:00:00.000
1          0    2013-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

My query, which I know is wrong, pulls the following results:

```
filekey  (No column name)           status
------------------------------------------
1         2011-01-01 00:00:00.000     1
```

I'm just not sure how to pull the correct status with the associated `effdate` without causing all sorts of errors to arise.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this.

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM
     (SELECT B.FILEKEY, B.STATUS AS STATUS, B.EFFDATE FROM TABLEB B
      UNION
      SELECT A.FILEKEY, A.STATUS2 AS STATUS, A.EFFDATE2 AS EFFDATE FROM TABLEA A) C
WHERE C.EFFDATE <= '5/1/2011')
ORDER BY C.EFFDATE DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  It works great.  However, as soon as this was available, I received another curveball:  How to add in yet another table?  In other words, status associated with filekeys that are at a particular location on a particular date.

Comment: @green I'm not sure what you mean. You might want to create another questions with the sample data etc.